# Tkinter RadioButton Entanglement

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was playing around with RadioButtons and had understood that all I need to do was use a different variable in order to have seperate groups of RadioButtons. Apparently you do not need seperate container controls as in many GUI systems.

I tried this, and found the two groups were entangled. So I stuck them on seperate containers; one on a canvas and the other on a frame. They are still entangled!

Here's the code:

```
# Radiobuttons on a Canvas
rvCanvas=tk.Canvas(root)
radioVariable=1 
tk.Radiobutton(rvCanvas, text="Set to one", variable=radioVariable,   value=1).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(rvCanvas, text="Set to two", variable=radioVariable, value=2).pack()
rvCanvas.place(x=300,y=20)


# Radiobuttons on a Frame
noincFrame=tk.Frame(root)
noInd=1
tk.Radiobutton(noincFrame, text="This one", variable=noInd, value=1).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(noincFrame, text="That too", variable=noInd, value=2).pack()
noincFrame.place(x=5,y=160)
```

So, how do we achieve disentangled RadioButtons?

Comment: the problem is that you need tkinter variables not normal python variables. change `radioVariable=1` to `radioVariable=tk.IntVar()` and the same for your other variable, then you can get the value with `radioVariable.get()` for ref: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables must be instances of the special tkinter variables (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc).

```
radioVariable = tk.IntVar(value=1)
...
noInd = tk.IntVar(value=1)
...
```

Comment: I'd missed the bit about requiring Tk variables. Thanks all.